# What is the difference between these two Enum(s) in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a String object:  `String theLanguage = "de";`

I have these Two Enums:-

**Enum 1:**

```
public enum Lang
{
   French("fr"),
   German("de"),
   English("en"), 
   Italian("it"),
   Spanish("sp");

   private String lang;

   Lang(String lang) {
      this.lang = lang;
   }

   public String lang() {
      return lang;
   }
}
```

and **Enum 2:**

```
public enum Lang
{
   French(1, "fr"),
   German(2, "de"),
   English(3, "en"), 
   Italian(4, "it"),
   Spanish(5, "sp");


   final int languageID;

   private final String code;

   Lang( int languageID, String code)
   {
      this.languageID = languageID;
      this.code= code;
   }
}
```

**------------------------ My Question -----------------------------**

**Q 1**- What is the **Difference** between these two Enums ( Basically in 2nd Enum, why there are int values) ?

**Q 2**- **What I need to Do** OR Add in 2nd Enum in Order **to Search/Match** the `theLanguage` object with Enum2. ?

Comment: 1) The difference is that whoever wrote #2 decided an integer identifier for each value was necessary.  That's it.  2) You can use `Lang.valueOf(theLanguage)`.

Comment: @Melvin, thanks but This is not an assessment-question, this type of question was asked in a programming interview, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - The second one can be searched for through both the string and int value (if for example you know the id of the language but not its code). Idk what "WhoisRIR" is doing in the place where your constructor should be.

2 - You need to add a getter for the code string and then foreach the enum until you find a element with code identical to `theLanguage`.

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd just has an extra parameter, the languageID

Add this code to 2nd Enum in order to search by code (e.g "de")

```
private static Map<String, Lang> reverseLookup = Arrays.stream(values())
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Lang::getCode, Function.identity()));

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public static Lang fromCode(final String code) {
    return reverseLookup.get(code);
}
```